# AWS deployed SpringBoot+Angular+Mysql throwing HttpResponseError 500 not letting me to know where the error comes from

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-error

Good day developers, i  half deployed this app to AWS using EB,RDS, and initially in its general data fetch endpoint, all works fine and all information is exposed , but when i disposed to create a new one through a second end point, the error

```
error: {timestamp: "2020-09-20T14:21:35.927+00:00", status: 500, error: "Internal Server Error", message: "", path: "/restaurant-booking/version1/booking/create"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
Http failure response for http://xxxx-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/restaurant-booking/version1/booking/create: 500 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/restaurant-booking/version1/booking/create"
```

despite of the element has been created on mySql.
I did try to check the logs of my RDS deployed database in order to see , but no data is exposed there (is logic cause the object gets created , dispite the error)

the error also shows a

```
zone-evergreen.js(ain't sure what oy means)
```

And double checking i use the same database with my app down , and all works perfect without any trace of that Error, but once i deployed to EB this happens

[image]

[image]

Im really trying hard to deploy this my first one to AWS helped by tutorials on internet ,im really struggling thus i do appreciate any hint about what i could do or where i could look at in order to find the core of this error.
Im also using Angular Material and mail sender configuration (app properties) when  this create process is activated.The first one in a Pop Up Dialog that shows up when the element is created, and the mail configuration sends a notification to the user about that creation

by the way i download the logs of my EC2 in this case the web-log,error-log,(there was a web-log-error, but it was empty)and for the first one this is what i found :

```
2020-09-21 06:35:21.836 ERROR 25536 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs
534-5.7.14 R7es95Sd93_3QucrGZqE05PKNaSV7YBkXzFeEs6NyDhb83WhRtK30nZepfns2VLWE9ffb
534-5.7.14 cKDtyt70SEYibdcd7npbYM2ADZh_5mu8EVGYL5icw2Vw_gsfyIGzlYL9ljRBKhI3>
534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 99sm9433971pjo.40 - gsmtp
] with root cause

javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs
534-5.7.14 R7es95Sd93_3QucrGZqE05PKNaSV7YBkXzFeEs6NyDhb83WhRtK30nZepfns2VLWE9ffb
534-5.7.14 cKDtyt70SEYibdcd7npbYM2ADZh_5mu8EVGYL5icw2Vw_gsfyIGzlYL9ljRBKhI3>
534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 99sm9433971pjo.40 - gsmtp
```

and referring to the EC2 error-log:

```
2020/09/20 11:39:11 [warn] 25513#0: *71 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 186.29.181.168, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/09/20 11:39:11 [warn] 25513#0: *71 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 186.29.181.168, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/09/20 11:39:11 [warn] 25513#0: *71 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 186.29.181.168, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/09/20 11:39:11 [warn] 25513#0: *71 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 186.29.181.168, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/09/20 13:48:59 [warn] 25513#0: *89 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 27.5.42.117, server: , request: "+/tmp/gpon80&ipv=0"
2020/09/20 13:48:59 [warn] 25513#0: *89 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 27.5.42.117, server: , request: "+/tmp/gpon80&ipv=0"
2020/09/20 13:48:59 [warn] 25513#0: *89 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 27.5.42.117, server: , request: "+/tmp/gpon80&ipv=0"
2020/09/20 13:48:59 [warn] 25513#0: *89 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 27.5.42.117, server: , request: "+/tmp/gpon80&ipv=0"
2020/09/20 14:39:11 [warn] 25513#0: *129 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 61.219.11.153, server: , request: "lv[endof]"
2020/09/20 14:39:11 [warn] 25513#0: *129 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 61.219.11.153, server: , request: "lv[endof]"
2020/09/20 14:39:11 [warn] 25513#0: *129 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 61.219.11.153, server: , request: "lv[endof]"
2020/09/20 14:39:11 [warn] 25513#0: *129 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 61.219.11.153, server: , request: "lv[endof]"
2020/09/20 15:26:14 [warn] 25513#0: *130 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 115.98.198.45, server: , request: "sh+/tmp/gpon80&ipv=0"
2020/09/20 15:26:14 [warn] 25513#0: *130 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 115.98.198.45, server: , request: "sh+/tmp/gpon80&ipv=0"
2020/09/20 15:26:14 [warn] 25513#0: *130 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 115.98.198.45, server: , request: "sh+/tmp/gpon80&ipv=0"
2020/09/20 15:26:14 [warn] 25513#0: *130 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 115.98.198.45, server: , request: "sh+/tmp/gpon80&ipv=0"
2020/09/20 16:20:08 [warn] 25513#0: *132 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 199.195.254.38, server: , request: "GET ../../proc/ HTTP"
2020/09/20 16:20:08 [warn] 25513#0: *132 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 199.195.254.38, server: , request: "GET ../../proc/ HTTP"
2020/09/20 16:20:08 [warn] 25513#0: *132 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 199.195.254.38, server: , request: "GET ../../proc/ HTTP"
2020/09/20 16:20:08 [warn] 25513#0: *132 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 199.195.254.38, server: , request: "GET ../../proc/ HTTP"
2020/09/20 22:18:16 [warn] 25513#0: *141 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 186.154.34.105, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/09/20 22:18:16 [warn] 25513#0: *141 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 186.154.34.105, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/09/20 22:18:16 [warn] 25513#0: *141 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 186.154.34.105, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/09/20 22:18:16 [warn] 25513#0: *141 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 186.154.34.105, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/09/21 04:35:34 [warn] 25513#0: *162 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 156.96.128.174, server: , request: "  üÇìí¦@Ë ä<C(¡³§¢5a¶š}X¸ÁîÕn  ¬À0À,À(À$ÀÀ"
2020/09/21 04:35:34 [warn] 25513#0: *162 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 156.96.128.174, server: , request: "  üÇìí¦@Ë ä<C(¡³§¢5a¶š}X¸ÁîÕn  ¬À0À,À(À$ÀÀ"
2020/09/21 04:35:34 [warn] 25513#0: *162 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 156.96.128.174, server: , request: "  üÇìí¦@Ë ä<C(¡³§¢5a¶š}X¸ÁîÕn  ¬À0À,À(À$ÀÀ"
2020/09/21 04:35:34 [warn] 25513#0: *162 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 156.96.128.174, server: , request: "  üÇìí¦@Ë ä<C(¡³§¢5a¶š}X¸ÁîÕn  ¬À0À,À(À$ÀÀ"
```

Comment: Did you check the beanstalk error log, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Comment: Hola Avi, i modify the question includiing the logs